# How to have Squid work with two NICs?

Tags: windows, routing, load-balancing, squid

I currently have a Squid 3 installation on Windows Server 2016 with a couple of rules to relay incoming data to different parent `cache_peer`s based on some preset `ACL`s.

```
 (10.0.1.5)
                    (172.16.0.1)
+----------+
| Parent A |       +------------+
+----------+-----> |            |
                   |  SquidSrv  |             +----+   +----+
                   |            |             | PC |   | PC |
+----------+-----> |            |======-> ... | 1  |...| 2  | ...
| Parent B |       +------------+             +----+   +----+
+----------+

 (10.0.2.6)
```

**The `Parent A` and `Parent B` are physically connected to `SquidSrv` using a single interface.**

I'd like to introduce a new NIC between `SquidSrv` and *both* of `Parent A` and `Parent B`. Let's consider this diagram:

```
 (10.0.1.5)
+----------+                    (172.16.0.1)
| Parent A |
+----+-----+                   +------------+
     |                  =====> |            |
     |    (intranet)   //  (1) |  SquidSrv  |
     *==============>>XX       |            |
     |                 \\  (2) |            | ===> ...
     |                  =====> |            |
+----+-----+                   +------------+
| Parent B |
+----------+
 (10.0.2.6)
```

**<sup>(Machines stay the same, they're omitted here.)</sup>**

Please notice that `(1)` and `(2)` represent the network cards, and `Parent A` and `Parent B` can both be accessed through either NIC 1 or NIC 2 from `SquidSrv`. Machines that access `SquidSrv` stay the same.

My plan is to have **machine 1** access both parents *only* through the **first NIC**, and have **machine 2** access both parents *only* through the **second NIC**.

At first, I thought it should be as simple as configuring *multiple gateways* in Squid and have it bind `ACL`s to each interface. However, it seems that Squid on Windows Server can't request routing through an interface. The closest thing that Google got me was `tcp_outgoing_address` which doesn't seem to do what I want.

One solution I can think of is to have TWO instances of Squid, each connected to a single NIC, and be accessed by `SquidSrv` with a local IP. However, I don't want to waste VM space with two sets of Squid installation and config files for achieving this purpose.

I also found a proprietary software called [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com/) which can in fact bind to individual NICs and provide SOCKS proxy, which could be relayed with [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/). But I don't want to introduce that into the mix.

Is there a simple way to route requests between two interfaces on Windows Servers? What would the best strategy be in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just add two /32 routes? `route -p add <ParentA> mask 255.255.255.255 <GATEWAY> metric 1 if <INTERFACE-NUMBER>` Interface Numbers are shown within the output of `route print`.

Comment: Are you trying to bond the interfaces for speed/resilience ?